# X subway line vs subway line X

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can the name of a bus/train/subway line come before and after the term "line" ? For instance, are both expressions below correct?

- subway line F
- F subway line

The former seems more usual to me, but I have recently heard from an American that the latter is also usual .

Answer (score 3):

Both usages occur; for example, in Boston (Massachusetts, USA), one refers to the lines of the “T” by color, so you might take a train on the “Blue line”; similarly in London (England), where the Underground/tube lines have names, so your train might be on the “Bakerloo line”, and in New York (New York, USA), where you might be riding on the “A train” or “7 train” on the subway system - but in Toronto (Ontario, Canada), the subway lines are referred to by number as “Line 1” through “Line 6”.

Comment: I agree that this is highly regional, and that the standard phrasing differs in each city. Chicago has "(color) line" and the Paris Métro has both numbers and colors for each line.

Comment: (The Métro is a bad example since they speak French there... oops)

Comment: @TypeIA - Yes, most of the examples that I'd been aware of for *line **x*** were actually translations from the French (Montreàl, Paris), Spanish (Madrid, Buenos Aires), or German (Berlin); I specifically wanted to limit it to English because this is _English_ Language Learners...